# optimize way of passing paramters from controller to model for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a project in condeigniter(newbie). My project include listing of products using different filters like categories, subcategories, keywords, minimum-maximum prices etc. I have done this hundred of times in custom php, where i make variable `$where` for all conditions in `where` clause. For example

```
$where = '';
if($category != '')
{
  $where .= " category = '$category'";
}
```

Now in codeigniter I have multiple paramters,which I can get in my `controller` through `uri segment` and call `model` function, pass all parameters and `run mysql query` there. The problem is I am checking every parameter if it is empty or set and run multiple queries accordingly. For example.

```
if($category != '' && $subCategory != '')
{
  //whole query here
}
else  if($category == '' && $subCategory != '')
{
  //whole query here
}

//and so on
```

What I need is any optimize way of doing this, as I have joins (multiple paramters).

My sample conditions and queries

```
if($subCat == '' && $vendor == '')
    {
        $cat = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$cat));
        $this->db->select('listings.* ');
        $this->db->from('listings');
        $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = listings.category');
        $this->db->where('categories.name',$cat);
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$page);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    else if($subCat == '' && $vendor != '')
    {
        $cat = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$cat));
        $this->db->select('listings.* ');
        $this->db->from('listings');
        $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = listings.category');
        $this->db->join('vendors','vendors.id = listings.programme');
        $this->db->where('categories.name',$cat);
        $this->db->where('vendors.name',$vendor);
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$page);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    else if($subCat != '' && $vendor == '')
    {
        $cat = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$cat));
        $this->db->select('listings.* ');
        $this->db->from('listings');
        $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = listings.category');
        $this->db->join('subcategories','subcategories.id = listings.subcategory');
        $this->db->where('categories.name',$cat);
        $this->db->where('subcategories.name',$subCat);
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$page);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        $cat = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$cat));
        $subCat = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$subCat));
        $vendor = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$vendor));

        $this->db->select('listings.* ');
        $this->db->from('listings');
        $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = listings.category');
        $this->db->join('subcategories','subcategories.id = listings.subcategory');
        $this->db->join('vendors','vendors.id = listings.programme');
        $this->db->where('categories.name',$cat);
        $this->db->where('subcategories.name',$subCat);
        $this->db->where('vendors.name',$vendor);
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$page);
        $query = $this->db->get();  
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: What about `arrays` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the query once only and not every time. For example you may have several conditions as you have described. For example, here is something what I have done:

```
$this->db->select('resource.id,city.name as city_name,city.provinceID,resource.Rate, skills.name')->from('resource')
->join('city','resource.cityID = city.id')
->join('resourceToSkillsMap','resource.id = resourceToSkillsMap.resourceID')
->join('skills','skills.id =  resourceToSkillsMap.skillsID');

if($category != '' && $subCategory != '') #condition
{
    $this->db->where('condition');
}
else  if($category == '' && $subCategory != '') #condition
{
    $this->db->where('condition');
}

$rs = $this->db->group_by('resource.id')
->limit($limit,$offset)
->get();
```

See how the query is written `only once` but the `where condition` is given inside the `if else`. SO your query will be build up that way. After the query is executed just `echo $this->db->last_query();` to echo the query and adjust it as you want it.

Comment: ok fine, I got this. Another question arises here. These conditions are not only needed for `where` clause, also needed for `joins`. For example if category is set, then i need joins for category table else not. 
-Note: I have categories, sub categories,products in different tables.

Comment: I am getting close according to your idea. I will put joins in codition as well. But every join have one where clause as well. For example ->join('categories','categories.id = paroducts.category_id') ->where('categories.id','$categoryid') If i have this combination in different conditions, it will effect joins and where sequence?

Comment: Yes, put `joins and where` inside the `if else` conditions. echo the query and test each `if else` condition separately.

Answer (score 1):

In your helper you can construct your `$where` `array()` like this

```
$where = array();
if($category != '')
{
   $where['category'] = $category;
} else {
   $where['someotherkey'] = 'someothervalue';
}
```

And in your controller you just pass the `$where` array while calling the model.

```
$this->foo_model->foo_method($where);
```

And in model you can do something like this

```
$this->db->where($where);
```

**EDIT**

```
if($category != '')
{
   //Along with your $this->db->where()
   $this->db->join('table1','condition1');
} else {
   //Along with your $this->db->where()
   $this->db->join('table2','condition2');
}
```

**To Tidy Up things**

```
$cat = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$cat));
$this->db->select('listings.* ');
$this->db->from('listings');
$this->db->join('categories','categories.id = listings.category');  
$this->db->where('categories.name',$cat);

if($vendor != '')      {
  $this->db->join('vendors','vendors.id = listings.programme');
  $this->db->where('vendors.name',$vendor);
}
if($subCat != ''){
  $subCat = str_replace("-"," ",str_replace("-and-"," & ",$subCat));
  $this->db->join('subcategories','subcategories.id = listings.subcategory');
  $this->db->where('subcategories.name',$subCat);
}    

$this->db->limit($perpage,$page);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: $where['category'] = '$category'; change this to $where['category'] = "'$category'";

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA thanks for pointing out. Have done that already :)

Comment: @Deepak, These conditions are not only needed for where clause, also needed for joins. For example if category is set, then i need joins for category table else not. -Note: I have categories, sub categories,products in different tables

Comment: @MShahzadKhan For that you can use @Nil'z answer and put the joins inside the conditions like `$this->db->join('table','condition');`

Comment: ok getting close. I will put joins in codition as well. But every join have one `where` clause as well. For example
->join('categories','categories.id = paroducts.category_id')
->where('categories.id','$categoryid')

If i have this combination in different conditions, it will effect `joins` and `where` sequence?

Comment: Check my edit. If that is not clear I might ask you to put some conditions so that i will understand better.

Comment: @Deepak, thanks for your response. I have added my code, please check edit.

Comment: @Deepak, Already did that :) Looking for optimize code :P
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan a bit more optimized ;)

Comment: @Deepak, This seems perfect. I was thinking of that, but i was afraid of sequence of `where` and `join`.
I already accepted Nil'z answer :( :P

Comment: @MShahzadKhan no no no thats fine credit goes to him. I just optimized it :)